# error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/influ1.git'

Tags: github, heroku, vscode, go

tengo un proyecto en VS Code que quiero enlazar a heroku, pero tengo problemas cuando creo el archivo "go.mod" y lo trato de subir a heroku con un "git push heroku master" me sigue apareciendo el error de la (1era imagen), ademas que el archivo "go.mod" cuando voy a la carpeta donde esta, aparece como archivo de video, asi una y otra vez que lo borro y vuelvo a colocarle la extension .mod (2da imagen), agradeceria su ayuda demasiado (voy empezando en GO)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]m/pJTfR.png

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sucede porque no tienes acceso a dicha rama.

Comment: Tienes un push rejected, puede ser que no sea un fast forward? haz un fetch y un pull antes de volver a intentarlo

Answer (score -1):

El archivo go.mod te lo está detectando Heroku.

Te falta añadir lo siguiente dentro del fichero go.mod para que detecte tu versión y el path a instalar, en tu caso la raíz del proyecto:

`// +heroku goVersion go1.14
// +heroku install ./...`

Son comentarios que Heroku detecta para realizar sus despliegues correctamente.

PD: Cuidado porque estás especificando una versión (1.23) que no está en release actualmente.